# How to set environment variables in Visual Studio 2017 RC1 using CMake?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, environment-variables, visual-studio-2017

I am using `Visual Studio 2017 RC1` to load a CMake Project (C++) using the new "Open Folder" feature and try to set environment variables for the binary upon launching.

Since there is no solution file anymore when using *Open Folder*, the pre-VS-2017 way of using the debugging dialogue doesn't seem to be an option here.

What I've tried so far:

- Using a simple Hello World project with one single source file
- Right Click on the corresponding C++ file in the solution explorer, selecting "*Debug and Launch Settings*"
- Added `env: {}` there, which should give the Hello World program an empty environment

[Screenshot of Solution Explorer and launch.vs.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPzN4.png)

However, if I try to run the binary a pop-up window shows up which says "**Object must implement IConvertible**" and the binary won't run. It works fine when omitting *`env: {}`*, though. I've also tried to add something to env, but the effect stays the same. Changing the working directory using *currentDir* works fine, so I assume that `launch.vs.json` is at least read and used.

Since the documentation on this seems quite sparse, I am not sure if this is even the intended way for setting Environment Variables when using the VS 2017 CMake integration.

Comment: I got one step further: apparently it has to be a string, so

    "env": "FOO=BAR"

is working. Next question is, how to set more than one environment variable ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to set multiple environment variables for VS 2017 with CMake, use `\u0000` as separator. For example, the put these in your `launch.vs.json` will set 2 environment variables `VAR1=USA` and `VAR2=JAPAN`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "defaults": {},
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "default",
      "name": "main.cpp",
      "project": "src\\main.cpp",
      "env": "VAR1=USA\u0000VAR2=JAPAN" 
    }
  ]
}
```